# Data import using CSV into DHIS 2

Tags: data, dhis2, import, csv

We have a lot of legacy data sitting on our Excel file that we need to import into our new DHIS2 database. How can we upload the data onto the DHIS using CSV?  It is costing us a lot in terms of time and money to employ data entry clerks to manually input the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSV import format which is described in this section of the docs:

https://docs.dhis2.org/master/en/developer/html/webapi_data_values.html#webapi_data_values_csv

You can either upload the file through the user interface from Apps > Import / Export > Data import, then select CSV as format.

You can also use the Web API to achieve the same, which is documented in this section:

https://docs.dhis2.org/master/en/developer/html/webapi_data_values.html#webapi_sending_bulks_data_values

Note that when using CSV format you must use the binary data option to preserve the line-breaks in the CSV file:

```
curl --data-binary @datavalueset.csv "https://play.dhis2.org/demo/24/api/dataValueSets" -H "Content-Type:application/csv" -u admin:district -v
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not try the Import Export option?

Under Apps > Import Export

Comment: This short answer looks promising.  Can you expand it?   You could: verify that this import function works for CSV, link to documentation, or explain what columns can be imported,